# I am trying to auto populate the report monthly using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

My task is that every month, the quantity column in the medicine table will be updated to the current month's column in the report table. I would like to do this without using task scheduler. I researched online about threading and timer. However, I am unsure if it will work as threading will only auto update the same column every month. As you can see, I need to update different columns every month.

Here are my codes:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
if (today == firstDay)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string sql1 = "SELECT quantity FROM medicine";
        DataSet ds = DBMgr.GetDataSet(sql1);
        int quantity = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["quantity"].ToString());
        string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");

    if (month.Equals("January"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET Jan = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("February"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET Feb = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("March"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET Mar = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("April"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET Apr = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);

    }
    if (month.Equals("May"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET May = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("June"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET June = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("July"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET July = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("August"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET Aug = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("September"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET Sep = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("October"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET Oct = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("November"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET Nov = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    if (month.Equals("December"))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE report SET Dec = '{0}'";
        DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql, quantity);
    }
    else
    {
        LblMsg.Text = "An Error Occurred";
    }
}
```

the current month's column was not updated at all. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that timer will work for your case. Most probably it is not called, because the current pool, that has a timer was stoped and there are no other requests to 'wake up' the pool and restart timer. Read about recycling app pools and [default settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720473(v=vs.71).aspx)

To be sure that your code is working, check it separatelly with another test

Comment: however if I rearranged the codes to have the while (true) as the first code, the page will just continue refreshing. Is there a way I can stop the while(true) loop?

Comment: you can stop `while(true)` loop with return or break see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2072a9/break-and-continue-statements-in-C-Sharp/